Failed building wheel for dlib Python windows
I am trying to install dlib library for python on windows. but it's not installing and gives the same each time as follows. as dlib is the core library for installing other face recognition libraries, so i can't install any of them.
File "<string>", line 130, in run
File "<string>", line 167, in build_extension
File "C:\Users\ZAKKI BOSS 
TRADES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in 
check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\ZAKKI BOSS 
TRADES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
1idhbtnl\\dlib_d3b40032553c4f9ab4cc6759080e6d32\\tools\\python', '- 
DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\ZAKKI BOSS 
TRADES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip- 
install-1idhbtnl\\dlib_d3b40032553c4f9ab4cc6759080e6d32\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython- 
39', 
'-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\ZAKKI BOSS 
TRADES\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe', '- 
DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\ZAKKI BOSS 
TRADES\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
1idhbtnl\\dlib_d3b40032553c4f9ab4cc6759080e6d32\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39', '- 
A', 
'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml- 
based projects

whatever i do it's the same as it is. I tried changing python versions, upgrading pip versions, installing multiple versions of dlib library.
